# dynamically product block in newsletter

Tags: magento-1.7, newsletter

Im looking for suggestion for adding dynamic product into newsletter automation have no idea how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call random Magento product collection in the newsletter.
catalog/product_list_random is to use here